# Weird background netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ide, editor

This background suddently appears when i am in editor writing codes. I don't know what triggers it.

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Looks like graphics card malfunction.

Comment: How do solve this

Comment: Try to update your graphics card driver. If the problem persists, you have to change the card.